# is it possible to use an iterated element in a "v-for" as a object key in data property?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

My case is like:

1. ```
   v-for="i in 10"
   ```
2. ```
   new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
       howManyRow: null,
       date: { 
               1: Sat Dec 28 2019 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time), 
               2: Sat Dec 28 2019 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)
              }
       } ...
   ```

I am trying to get something like `{{ date[i] }}` to display but it is not working.

I also made an example for this issue, in this case, I want to let the `"Display: [Date]"` in each row working (currently not showing any date).

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Arthur998/tcLw81jk/78/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because of the reactivity issue. Just replace the updateDate method with following function and it works.

```
    updateDate: function (data) {
    //this.date[data.dateIndex] = data.date;
    this.$set(this.date,data.dateIndex,data.date)
  },
```

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ynug7kLx/

Comment: BTW,  I am always quite confused about the reactivity problems, is there any document or tutorial explaining this kind of issue?